# Using Value From One View in Another View Django

Tags: python, django

In View 1's form their is a field called 'reference'.  I need to access whatever value is submitted in that field in View 2 and set a variable equal to it.  Right now I am just getting an error "orders matching query does not exist".

This is what I'm trying (I've commented the code in view2 to indicate where im getting the error).

views.py

```
def view1(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Manifests, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('view2')

    else:
        form = CreateManifestForm(instance=item)

        return render(request, 'edit_manifest_frombrowse.html', {'form': form})



def view2(request):
    form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()

            ...



    reference_id =  request.POST.get('reference') #this is how Im trying to get reference from the previos view

    data = Manifests.objects.all().filter(reference__reference=reference_id)
    form = CreateManifestForm(initial={

         'reference': Orders.objects.get(reference=reference_id), #this is where im getting "does not exist"

         })
    total_cases = Manifests.objects.filter(reference__reference=reference_id).aggregate(Sum('cases'))

    context = {
    'reference_id': reference_id,
    'form': form,
    'data': data,
    'total_cases': total_cases['cases__sum'],

     }

    return render(request, 'manifest_readonly.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class CreateManifestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Manifests
        fields = ('reference', 'cases', 'product_name', 'count', 'CNF', 'FOB')
```

I just want to be able to use whatever value is submitted in the 'reference' field in view1 in view2 and assign it equal to `reference_id`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
from django.urls import reverse

def view1(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Manifests, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save()
            reference_id =  request.POST.get('reference') or obj.reference.id
            return redirect(reverse('view2')+f'?reference={reference_id}')

    else:
        form = CreateManifestForm(instance=item)
    return render(request, 'edit_manifest_frombrowse.html', {'form': form})

def view2(request):   
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()

            ...
    data = getattr(request, 'POST', None) or getattr(request, 'GET', {})
    reference_id =  data.get('reference') #this is how Im trying to get reference from the previos view

    data = Manifests.objects.all().filter(reference__reference=reference_id)
    form = CreateManifestForm(initial={

         'reference': Orders.objects.get(reference=reference_id), #this is where im getting "does not exist"

         })
    total_cases = Manifests.objects.filter(reference__reference=reference_id).aggregate(Sum('cases'))

    context = {
    'reference_id': reference_id,
    'form': form,
    'data': data,
    'total_cases': total_cases['cases__sum'],

     }

    return render(request, 'manifest_readonly.html', context)
```

Comment: I am attempting to replicate your response and I am receiving a syntax error on the line ``` return redirect(reverse('manifest')+f'?reference={reference_id}')```. Any thoughts how I can resolve that? I'm not sure what the error is

Comment: Just upgrade your python to 3.6+